# Not able to use for after using csv reader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am given the task to write a script to check MX records of the given data in the CSV file. I have started by trying checking it using regex and before that I trying to read the CSV file. I would also like to log the progress so I am printing the row number it is on, but whenever I use the cvs_reader object to calculate the row length I am unable to get inside the for loop

```
import csv
with open('test_list.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    data = list(csv_reader)
    row_count = len(data)
    for row in csv_reader:
            print({row[2]})
            line_count += 1
            print('Checking '+ str(line_count) +' of '+ str(row_count))    
    print('Processed lines :'+str(row_count))
```

I only get the result as 
Processed lines : 40 
New at python scripting. Please help

My test_list.csv look like this

```
fname, lname, email
bhanu2, singh2, bhanudoesnotexist@doesnotexit.com
bhanu2, singh2, bhanudoesnotexist@doesnotexit.com
bhanu2, singh2, bhanudoesnotexist@doesnotexit.com
bhanu2, singh2, bhanudoesnotexist@doesnotexit.com
Total 40 times continued
```

Comment: Maybe you should print  also `data` to help debugging?

Comment: What are you expecting and how is `Processed lines : 40` not the correct output? It would be helpful if you could post a sample data from `tset_list.csv` and your desired output.

Comment: i don't think its the problem of csv data, problems itsw not getting into the for loop because of `data = list(csv_reader)
    row_count = len(data)` these 2 lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first thing csv data has nothing to do with this problem,

**Solution:**

```
import csv

input_file = open("test_list.csv", "r").readlines()
print(len(input_file))
csv_reader = csv.reader(input_file)

line_count = 0
# data = list(csv_reader)
# row_count = len(data)

for row in csv_reader:
    print({row[2]})
    line_count += 1
    print('Checking ' + str(line_count) + ' of ' + str(len(input_file)))
print('Processed lines :' + str(len(input_file)))
```

---

**Problem Recognition:**

```
with open('test_list.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    data = list(csv_reader)
    row_count = len(data)
```

in your code `data = list(csv_reader)` because of this line you are exhausting your variable. so it won't be able to loop through in your for loop

so for that you can read csv file like

```
input_file = open("test_list.csv", "r").readlines()
print(len(input_file))
```

then use `csv.reader()`

Answer (score 2):

`csv.reader` returns an iterable, and when you use `list(csv_reader)` to read all the rows of the CSV, you have already exhausted the iterable, so when you want to iterate through `csv_reader` again with a `for` loop, it has nothing left to iterate.

Since you have a complete list of rows materialized in the variable `data`, you can simply iterate over it instead.

Change:

```
for row in csv_reader:
```

to:

```
for row in data:
```